# When i destroy my app using task manager,Again open same app its open next Activity instead of first activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-lifecycle, android-sharedpreferences

I am having issue when i destroy my app using task manager again open in the app its showing next activity instead of first activity, kindly help me to solve the problem

Comment: kindly share your code.

Comment: Are you sure that you destroy the same app that you open again? For example, if you have different build flavors installed you could destroy one app flavor and open another one...

Comment: What is your Launching Activity. What Your  firstActivity and nextActivity name and how you navigate share your code or process ..

Comment: Hi, my first activity its register class having username and mobile number after register it will be checking in otp number in second activity, in second activity set the  otp number and click it will goes next activity,,, my problem is when i am not given  the otp number in second activity and clear app using task manager after open the app it will open next activity instead open first activity..

Comment: hi Rob Meeuwisse, yes i am sure destroy the app

Comment: post the manifest.